# Selecting sublists of a list of lists to define a relation

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop, sublist

If I happen to have the following list of lists:

```
L=[[(1,3)],[(1,3),(2,4)],[(1,3),(1,4)],[(1,2)],[(1,2),(1,3)],[(1,3),(2,4),(1,2)]]
```

and what I wish to do, is to create a relation between lists in the following way:

I wish to say that

```
[(1,3)] and [(1,3),(1,4)]
```

are related, because the first is a sublist of the second, but then I would like to add this relation into a list as:

```
Relations=[([(1,3)],[(1,3),(1,4)])]
```

but, we can also see that:

```
[(1,3)] and [(1,3),(2,4)]
```

are related, because the first is a sublist of the second, so I would want this to also be a relation added into my Relations list:

```
Relations=[([(1,3)],[(1,3),(1,4)]),([(1,3)],[(1,3),(2,4)])]
```

The only thing I wish to be careful with, is that I am considering for a list to be a sublist of another if they only differ by ONE element. So in other words, we cannot have:

```
([(1,3)],[(1,3),(2,4),(1,2)])
```

as an element of my Relations list, but we SHOULD have:

```
([(1,3),(2,4)],[(1,3),(2,4),(1,2)])
```

as an element in my Relations list.

I hope there is an optimal way to do this, since in the original context I have to deal with a much bigger list of lists.

Any help given is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really haven't provided enough information, so can't tell if you need `itertools.combinations()` or `itertools.permutations()`. Your examples work with `itertools.combinations` so will use that.

If `x` and `y` are two elements of the list then you just want all occurrences where the `set(x).issubset(y)` and the size of the set difference is `<= 1` - `len(set(y) - set(x)) <= 1`, e.g.:

```
In []:
[[x, y] for x, y in it.combinations(L, r=2) if set(x).issubset(y) and len(set(y)-set(x)) <= 1]

Out[]:
[[[(1, 3)], [(1, 3), (2, 4)]],
 [[(1, 3)], [(1, 3), (1, 4)]],
 [[(1, 3)], [(1, 2), (1, 3)]],
 [[(1, 3), (2, 4)], [(1, 3), (2, 4), (1, 2)]],
 [[(1, 2)], [(1, 2), (1, 3)]],
 [[(1, 2), (1, 3)], [(1, 3), (2, 4), (1, 2)]]]
```